# Fastlane Match Provisioning profile "match Development XXX" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Development: XXXX"

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

I'm using fastlane to build my app and I'm unable to build at the moment.

In code I can see this error "match Development XXX" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Development: XXXX".

[image: XCode Error]

I've checked that it's on my local keychain

[image: Keychain showing certificates]

I've checked that the correct certificate is part of the providing profile

[image: apple developer showing development certificate is checked]

I've run

`fastlane nuke development`

`fastlane nuke distribution`

Both have been run twice.

Match doesnt' download the proper certificate?

Matchfile

```
git_url("git@github.com:REPO/iOS-Profile.git")

storage_mode("git")

type("development") # The default type, can be: appstore, adhoc, enterprise or development

app_identifier(["XXX.dev", "XX.Tests"])
clone_branch_directly(true)
# username("user@fastlane.tools") # Your Apple Developer Portal username

# For all available options run `fastlane match --help`
# Remove the # in the beginning of the line to enable the other options

# The docs are available on https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting not only the certificate, but the private keys on keychain fixed the problem on CI. I still see this locally, but it's not a blocker